# how to open YouTube viode within my website without changing URL

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube

I have a link in menu of my website named Video, I want to show users a YouTube video but I do not want to jump to YouTube website. I want to show it within my web site like the one below. I visited this on a website

[image]

it is something like a player in website. is there any way I can implement something like this? appreciate any help very much.

here is the code which I have to show video if needed.

```
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="main-menu"><span class="text">documents</span><span class="fa fa-angle-down icons-dropdown"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-1">
                 <li>
                 <a href="http://www.youtube.com/....." class="link-page"> <span class="text">vidéo</span></a>
                </li>


            </ul>
    </li>
```

Comment: Go the youtube video. Click `share`. Click `Embed`. Copy the html code to your page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest for you to use modal link for this
Check snippet sample below.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myModal").on("hidden.bs.modal",function(){
    $("#iframeYoutube").attr("src","#");
  })
})

function changeVideo(vId){
  var iframe=document.getElementById("iframeYoutube");
  iframe.src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+vId;

  $("#myModal").modal("show");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<li><a href="index.html">Document</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown">
                    <li><a onclick="changeVideo('pu1jqT5dPj0')">video</a></li>
 
                  </ul>
                </li>
    
    
    <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
      
        <iframe id="iframeYoutube" width="560" height="315"  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/e80BbX05D7Y" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> 
        
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want some modification you can check this link https://appleple.github.io/modal-video/.

If you use bootstrap use can read this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

You can play with the properties base on your requirements.

Comment: @nedaDerakhshesh you're using a bootstrap?

Comment: thank you solved . it shows completely fine but close button closes the window but it dose not stop the video. sounds still playing in the background. I do not know how to thank you,Appreciate if you help me in stopping the video also, and yes I am using bootstrap

Comment: This is different question it depends on how you apply. If you follow my answer supposedly the video will stop. But if you follow bootstrap modal documentation then just add the youtube iframe to modal body no need to follow my javascript and add this code $('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function () { $('div.modal-body').html('');

Answer (score 1):

```css
#yt{display:none;}
```

```html
  <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="main-menu"><span class="text">documents</span><span class="fa fa-angle-down icons-dropdown"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-1">
                 <li>
                 <a  onclick="document.getElementById('yt').style.display='block'" class="link-page"> <span class="text">vidéo</span></a>
                </li>


            </ul>
    </li>
    <div id="yt">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/lJIrF4YjHfQ" frameborder="0" gesture="media" allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
```

you need to use the integer option in youtube panel

Comment: thank you very much . it works fine but do you know what to do with `CSS` to  show it some how when user clicks on link then whole page becomes dark and disable and video shows in center? I forgot what is the exact name of doing something like this

Comment: yeah it's possible just validate my answer with the sign near to my answer, the thing what you say is called an overlay

Comment: why do you uncheck my answer?

Comment: thank you very very very much, the problem solved. you helped a lot. but the other answer was more complete near to what I need, thank you again

Answer (score 0):

you can use iframe to show video of youtube

but you have to hide iframe & show onclick
css:

```
iframe{
display:none;
}
```

```css
iframe{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<iframe width="420" height="345" src="">
</iframe>
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k" onclick="javascript:document.GetElementByTagName('iframe').src=this.href;
document.GetElementByTagName('iframe').style.display="block";">adas</a>
```